# How to select XML node with namespace

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xmldocument

I need to get the list of `<Item>` nodes under the 2nd `<Folder>` node. If I use the following XML source and C# code, FolderNode is set to the correct node (2nd `<Folder>` node) but ItemsList gets set to a collection of every `<Item>` in the file, including the items in the 1st folder node. So, ItemsList contains 5 items instead of 3.

XML Source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MMM xmlns="http://some.url.com/2.0">
    <Document>
        <open>1</open>
        <Folder>
            <name>Folder_1_Data</name>
            <Item>
                <description>Folder 1 Item 1</description>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <description>Folder 1 Item 2</description>
            </Item>
        </Folder>
        <Folder>
            <name>Folder_2_Data</name>
            <Item>
                <description>Folder 2 Item A</description>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <description>Folder 2 Item B</description>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <description>Folder 2 Item C</description>
            </Item>
        </Folder>
    </Document>
</MMM>
```

C# Code:

```cs
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("Import.xml");
    var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("abc", "http://some.url.com/2.0");
    var xnlNodes = doc.SelectNodes("//abc:Document", nsmgr);
    var FolderNode = doc.SelectNodes("//abc:Folder", nsmgr).Item(1);

    var ItemsList = FolderNode.SelectNodes("//abc:Item", nsmgr);
    //Loop through each item in the 2nd folder node
    //and pull out the description of each item.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to add a leading `.` to indicate that the XPath is relative to current `FolderNode` :

```cs
var ItemsList = FolderNode.SelectNodes(".//abc:Item", nsmgr);
                                      //^notice this dot
```

Since `<Item>` nodes are direct child of `<Folder>` node, you can also do this way :

```cs
var ItemsList = FolderNode.SelectNodes("abc:Item", nsmgr);
                                      //without symbols at the beginning which..
                                      //^.. will return only direct children nodes
```

or this way :

```cs
var ItemsList = FolderNode.SelectNodes("./abc:Item", nsmgr);
                                      //^using single slash which also return.. 
                                      //.. only direct children nodes
```